# Dropbox upload with Oauth2 code loads to 'wrong' folder

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, dropbox-api

I am trying to upload a file to a shared folder using python and the Dropbox API.

The problem that I have is that I have specified the target file name as:

```
'/<shared folder name>/uploaded.txt'
```

but it uploads to:

```
'Apps/<app name>/<shared folder name>/uploaded.txt'
```

This is not a shared folder and I specifically want to use the shared folder. How can I change my code so that it uploads to the shared folder?

```
import webbrowser

from dropbox import Dropbox
from dropbox.files import WriteMode
from dropbox import DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect

APP_KEY = '<my app key>'
APP_SECRET = '<my app secret>'
APP_TOKEN = '<my app token>'

def upload(dbx):
    local_file = '<path to local file>'
    remote_file = '/<shared folder name>/uploaded.txt'
    with open(local_file, 'rb') as f_upload:
        try:
            foo = dbx.files_upload(f_upload.read(), remote_file, 
                                   mode=WriteMode('overwrite'))
            print('done ...', foo)
        except:
            print('Upload error')

def get_dbx_with_auth_code():
    auth_flow = DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET)
    authorize_url = auth_flow.start()
    webbrowser.open(authorize_url)
    auth_code = input('Authorization code: ').strip()
    try:
        oauth_result = auth_flow.finish(auth_code)
    except:
        print('Token error')
        return None
    dbx = Dropbox(oauth_result.access_token)
    return dbx

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dbx = get_dbx_with_auth_code()
    upload(dbx)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is uploading into an app folder (e.g., under `'/Apps/<app name>'` as you indicated), that means that the access token you're using is for an app that has the "app folder" permission. Apps with this permission can only operate inside the special app folder created for them. You can find [more information on the different Dropbox API app permissions here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/developer-guide#app-permissions).

If you need to operate in shared folders, you'll need to [register an app](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps/create) for the "full Dropbox" permission instead, and switch to using an access token for that app.